# Fetch file in Python. flask code coming from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

This is my javascript function which is routing a csv file to /uploader.

```
function getData() {
var csv=document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
var formData=new FormData();
formData.append("uploadCsv",csv);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Open first, before setting the request headers.
request.open("POST", "/uploader", true);
//here you can set the request header to set the content type, this can be avoided.
//The browser sets the setRequestHeader and other headers by default based on the formData that is being passed in the request.
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data"); //----(*)
request.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
    console.log(request.response);
    }
}

request.send(formData);
```

}

My python function does get invoked to the app routing part seems to correct. However the `request.files` length is 0.
This is the python code -

```
@app.route("/uploader", methods=["POST"])
def post_javascript_data():
  f = request.files["uploadCsv"]
  print(f)
  return "OK"
```

In the picture below you can see the request.files length remains 0. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Your question has already been answered, but it's best to use `request.files.get('FILENAME')` and check if it isn't `None`.

Comment: removing `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data"); //----(*)` resolved and yes it is better to use `request.files.get('FILENAME')`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not manually set the header for the content type. This is set automatically.

The following is an example with XMLHttpRequest and alternatively with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Using XMLHttpRequest -->
    <form name="upload-form-1">
      <input type="file" name="upload-csv" accept="text/csv" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        let form = document.querySelector("form[name='upload-form-1']");
        form.addEventListener(
          "submit",
          (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/uploader");
            xhr.onload = function() {
              if(this.status === 200) {
                console.log(this.response);
              } else {
                console.error(`Error ${this.status} occurred.`)
              }
            }
            xhr.send(new FormData(event.target));
          },
          false);
      })();
    </script>

    <!-- Using Fetch -->
    <form name="upload-form-2">
      <input type="file" name="upload-csv" accept="text/csv" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        let form = document.querySelector("form[name='upload-form-2']");
        form.addEventListener(
          "submit",
          (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch("/uploader", {
              method: "POST",
              body: new FormData(event.target)
            }).then(resp => {
              console.log(resp);
            }).catch(err => {
              console.error(err);
            });
          },
          false);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import abort, make_response, request

@app.route('/uploader', methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
    if 'upload-csv' in request.files:
        f = request.files['upload-csv']
        # Use the object of the type werkzeug.FileStorage here.
        return make_response('')
    abort(400)
```

Have fun implementing your project.